# How to create a form that adapts to the number of users with django 2?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am biginner wiht django, and I would like to create a form that could adapt him to the number of user. 
The goal is to declare the presence or not of employees and the number of hours they worked during the day, knowing that the number of employees can change from one day to another.
So I thought of creating two variables : an integer counting the number of hours performed during the day, and another boolean corresponding to the presence or not of the employee, and being reproduced as many times as there are employees.

So, I tested that :

forms.py :

```
class HoursDeclarationForm(forms.Form):
    number_of_hours = forms.FloatField(required=True)
    for user in User.objects.all():
        presence = forms.BooleanField(label="{0} {1}".format(
            User.first_name,
            User.last_name
            )
        )
```

views.py :

```
def hours_declaration (request):
    form = HoursDeclarationForm(request.POST or None)

    return render (
        request,
        'HoursDeclaration/hours_declaration.html'
        , locals()
        )
```

hours_declaration.html :

```
<h1>Ceci est la page ou tu peux attribuer à chaque salarié le nombre 
d'heure qu'il a effectué.<h1>
<form action="{% url "hours_declaration" %}" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

But I get a single checkbox preceded by: "django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x00000255505DEF98 django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x00000255505DEFD0" :, no matter the number of users.
Please forgive me if the wording of my sentences is not correct, I am not very good in English, 
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to implement some sort of widget through a form field. I am not sure that is a good idea. The field should probably be a [**`ModelMultipleChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField), and perhaps you can use a [**`CheckboxSelectMultiple`** widget [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple). We thus can implement this with:

```
class HoursDeclarationForm(forms.Form):
    number_of_hours = forms.FloatField(required=True)
    presense = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
```

Comment: How should I make my view to save the form data in the database?  I guess presence.user does not work?  Thank you for everything.

Comment: @RobinJoseph: the `cleaned_data` will contain a list of `User` objects. So you will need to define some model (with a relation to a `User`) to store data in the database.

Comment: @WilemVanOnsem yes, I know that, and I have a model    class UserExtention (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='utilisateur')
    phone_number = models.CharField (max_length = 10, null = True, blank=True, verbose_name='numéro de téléphone')
    hours_number = models.IntegerField (null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="nombre d'heure effectuée par le salarié")
, but I don't understand how should I  do my view for get the form's data, and register them in the database. How should I get the datas for every user, individually